# Laravel Homestead 5.3, can't php artisan migrate although .env and database.php info is correct

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Just having some issue trying to php artisan migrate a mysql database to work on in a local environment. I have been trying all day to get my database to migrate, and everything I could dig up tells me that my credentials should be correct.

database.php

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'homestead'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'homestead'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'secret'),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
    ]
```

as for my .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

I have tried php artisan config:clear and read through the documentations and tried nearly all of the fixes suggested by other users on similar questions to no avail.

Comment: Whats the error you got?

Comment: Forgot to iterate that! D'oh.

I get error 1045: Access denied for user "homestead" @ "local host" (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table schema= homestead and table_name=migrations)

I am running WAMP currently.

Comment: your database username-password is wrong.

Comment: Either your database username and password is wrong.... or you're running `php artisan migrate` from *outside* Homestead. Be sure to SSH into Homestead first. This will allow you to connect to Homestead's localhost rather than your own native MySQL connection (if one exists).

Answer (score 1):

if you're running php artisan migrate command outside homestead, you should change the port to 33060. then change it back again to 3306 after migration.

otherwise you need to do it inside homestead via an SSH connection (vagrant ssh)

Comment: great! using `ssh` is way easier than modifying the `.env` so often.

Answer (score 0):

from your data, you should have

mysql -u homestead -h localhost -p secret

[enter link description here][see this answer]

set password and grant privelege

```
mysql>  SET PASSWORD FOR 'homestead'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('secret');
```

grant priveleges to your database

```
GRANT SELECT ON homestead.* TO 'homestead'@'secret';
```

in the above code first homestead represents database name

try flush privileges from mysql client

```
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```